# Mails bouncing back from Dovecot mail server

Tags: centos, email, dovecot

we have a dedicated server running CENTOS 6.6 x86_64 standard running and usually comes with whm/cpanel.  It is using Dovecot mail server and postfix is excluded in repository. The problems we are facing is most of emails are bouncing back for some reason and some of them totally go off tracing with no record, no failed delivery email is sent back.

the error is

```
  username@somedomain.com
host mx00.1and1.co.uk [212.227.15.41]
SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:
554-kundenserver.de (mxeue006) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available
554-No SMTP service
554 invalid DNS PTR resource record, IP=82.145.34.49
```

I have also (clamav & spamd) installed. whenever I restart exim it auto restart them 2.

thanks,

Comment: You need an MTA (postfix, exim, etc.) to receive email.  Dovecot is a MDA (Mail Delivery Agent) not a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent.

Comment: Phrases like "for some reason" are totally meaningless here. You need to post the relevant output from the log files and include the error messages that you're receiving.

Comment: Do you configure your email subsystem through whm/cpanel?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry I was on break for few days, yes I do have ( exim ) but I don't know how to configure it, sometime ssh and sometime whm/cpanel if can't do it in ssh, but I prefer ssh.

Comment: I've added an error message returned from the email to the post.

Comment: Is there by any chance spamd is playing some role in bouncing back emails?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following actions have solved the problems. Most of emails are now going through but just a few 
bounce back.

1. Changing my email server from Dovecot to Courier.
2. Temporary disable auto response emails to avoid the long queue.
3. Enable rDNS lookup.

Found this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629614/whitelisting-website-email-so-it-is-not-rejected-as-spam which was very helpful and I think following all steps in this article may solve the rest of problems.

Thanks for information about exim and clarity between MDA and MTA. Checked all logs of exim that leads me to above resources and actions.